# "full-window" slideshow image stretching bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If you go to the slideshow I am working on [here](http://henrybuilt.com/slideshow/), you can see that the image resizes and moves correctly if you resize the browser window.

...unless you make the browser window's width smaller than a certain amount (i can't tell what defines that amount) and then it stretches the image instead of scaling it. How can I fix this?

Here is my resize code:

```
winWidth = $(window).width();
winHeight = $(window).height();
ratio = winWidth/winHeight;
if(ratio > imgRatio){
    $('#curImg img').css({width:winWidth});
    imgWidth = winWidth;
    imgHeight = $('#curImg img').height();
    $("#curImg img").css({top: (-1*Math.round((imgHeight-winHeight)/2)) + "px"});
    $("#curImg").css({height: winHeight + "px"});
}else{
    $('#curImg img').css({height:winHeight});
    imgHeight = winHeight;
    imgWidth = $('#curImg img').width();
    $("#curImg img").css({left: (-1*Math.round((imgWidth-winWidth)/2)) + "px"});
    $("#curImg").css({width: winWidth + "px"});
}
```

Comment: what version?.. mine works fine. it just has a 20px black area below the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also check out this jQuery plugin:
http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/

Or CSS tricks which looks at multiple solutions:
http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look to tha [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-size) properties, especially at the `cover` values

Comment: True, and quite well supported these days.

http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/
http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts

Answer (score 0):

Something I wrote that works:

```
//oWidth - container width
//oHeight - container height
//iWidth = image width
//iHeight = image height

    iRatio = iWidth/iHeight;
    wRatio = oWidth/oHeight;

    if(iRatio<wRatio){
        imageWidth = oWidth;
        imageHeight = Math.ceil(iHeight*(oWidth/iWidth));

    }
    else{
        imageHeight = oHeight;
        imageWidth = Math.ceil(iWidth*(oHeight/iHeight));

    }

    $('#backgroundResizeImage').css({ 
        'height': imageHeight,
        'width': imageWidth
    });
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote your example a bit to make a self-contained demonstration.

Two notes unrelated to your question.

1. Make sure to cache any of your jQuery objects. You don't want to fetch items repeatedly, as that comes with an unnecessary performance cost.
2. My example shows this happening in the resize event for the window - I'm not sure how you had yours set up. For production, it's very important to throttle events bound to things like the window resize event, since they can be fired as fast as a browser can manage, which can lead to bad consequences. See [this excellent article by John Resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/) on a time this bit Twitter in the ass.

The biggest relevant change is that I altered the way it's setting the heights and widths of images depending on how their ratio compares to the window. I think this way is a little clearer, but that's subjective. But it does work!

http://jsfiddle.net/L4k3s/2/

```
var $window = $(window),
    $img = $('img'),
    imgRatio = $img.width() / $img.height();

$window.on('resize', function (event) {
    var imgWidth = $img.width(),
        imgHeight = $img.height(),
        winWidth = $window.width(),
        winHeight = $window.height(),
        ratio = winWidth / winHeight;

    // The image is wider than the window
    if (ratio < imgRatio) {
        $img.width(winWidth);
        $img.height(winWidth / imgRatio);
        $img.css({
            left: 0,
            top: (-1 * Math.round((imgHeight - winHeight) / 2)) + "px"
        });
    // The image is taller than the window
    } else {
        $img.width(winHeight * imgRatio);
        $img.height(winHeight);
        $img.css({
            left: (-1 * Math.round((imgWidth - winWidth) / 2)) + "px",
            top: 0
        });
    }
});
```

​